# Java: search through a String to find all consonants and add letter `O` next to it plus the constant

Tags: java

This is the problem I am trying to do. I search through a `String` for example `hello` to find all consonants and add letter `O` next to it plus the constant. So for `hello` it would be `hohelololoo`.

So far this is my code:

```
public class testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "hello eeron";
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(word);
        char[] array = word.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i) != 'e') {
                str.insert(i + 1,'o').insert(i + 2,str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

When I try to run it I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3326)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.insert(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1187)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(StringBuilder.java:338)
    at testing.main(testing.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, class names are upper case by convention. 
Second thing, your code is wrong from the beginning. It should print word, with double consonants, and 'o' char between them. your code doubles vowel 'e' and add 'o' between them. Probably this is not the most effective way, but check this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter word: ");
    String word = scanner.nextLine();
    char[] constants = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y','Å', 'Ä','Ö'}; //array with vovels,
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
    char[]array = word.toCharArray();                               //divide word into char array,

    for(char a : array){                                            //for every char in word,
        if(!isPresent(a,constants) && Character.isLetter(a)){       // if char a is not vowel and is a letter,
            str.append(a+"o"+Character.toString(a).toLowerCase());  // add double with 'o' beetween, to stringBuilder,
        }else{                                                      
            str.append(a);                                          // if not, add just char (it could be ' ', '!', or another non-letter,
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}

    public static boolean isPresent(char ch, char[] inArray){       //method return true, if char is equal to wanted char, in this case to vowel
    for(char a : inArray){
        String constant = Character.toString(a).toLowerCase();      // toLowerCase because we ewanto to ignore case,
        String character = Character.toString(ch).toLowerCase();    // same,
            if(String.valueOf(constant).equals(character)){         // if char is a vowel,
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
}
```

You need to pay more attention for content of the task